# javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter leaking class loaders?

Tags: java, tomcat, jaxb, classloader

I am currently investigating some class loader leaks of an application on Tomcat 7 (w/ Oracle JDK 7). One class that keeps a static reference to the web application class loader (and thus causes the class loader not to be released on redeploy/restart) is `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`, which lives in the system class loader and keeps a static reference via its `theConverter` field to `com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl` from Sun's jaxb-impl package.

Has anyone ever observed this issue before? Any suggestions (except for using reflection to null the static field on application shutdown)?

Comment: More details on the problem is given in this set of blogposts: http://java.jiderhamn.se/category/classloader-leaks/ (search for 'jaxb' in the text for a description of the issue that you're describing).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As it turned out, one of my dependencies (`com.sun.jersey:jersey-json`) pulled in `com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl`, which was responsible for the System Classloader -> Application Classloader reference. Excluding that dependency solved the issue (as JDK 7 comes with a sensible JAXB implementation, which will be referenced within the System CL, which is fine).

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat 8 issue warning on subsequent web application redeploy during development:

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks

SEVERE: The web application [rsnetlombard] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
[com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1] (value [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1@79eb7926])
and a value of type [java.util.WeakHashMap]
(value [{class javax.xml.bind.annotation.W3CDomHandler=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@525eec52}])
but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped.
Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

I make heap dump within VisualVM and open it.

VisualVM find destroyed web application class loader in OQL tab by query:

```
select x from org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader x where x.state.name.toString() == "DESTROYED"
```

Visiting pointed link to object in "instalce" tab allow call "Find nearest GC root" in "reference
section" and copy textual representation to clipboard::

```
this     - value: org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader #3
 <- <classLoader>     - class: com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl, value: org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader #3
  <- <class>     - class: com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl, value: com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl class DatatypeConverterImpl
   <- theConverter (sticky class)     - class: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter, value: com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl #1
```

`javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` is from Java SE and that class loaded by system classloader
(and so marked `(sticky class)`). But point to class that loaded by web application classloader.

Googling about `com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl` leads to this SO post.

Supplied solution say that `com.sun.jersey:jersey-json` package request JAXB API implementation
from `com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl` package::

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
...
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.7.1:compile
```

Because Java 7 comes with own JAXB implementation ([JAXB RI](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Which_JAXB_RI_is_included_in_which_JDK_.html) by the fact) we don't need `com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl`
package. Add exclude to corresponding part of `pom.xml`::

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

In order reach results quicker in test I reduce Tomcat memory::

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx212m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:MaxPermSize=66m"
```

Redeploing/using application 10 times give none for::

```
select x from org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader x where x.state.name.toString() == "DESTROYED"
```

Under redeploys "Visual GC" plug-in shown PermGen cleanups.

Running with previous development setup require something::

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

to survive 4-5 redeploys. OQL query for larger PermGen give several Tomcat's `WebappClassLoader`
but examining instances shown that there are no path to GC and they are cleaned when PermGen become
full.